# Formulario Laravel, Select de una foreign Key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tabla Productos:

> Primary Key-> codigo_producto

Tabla Movimientos :

> Primary Key-> codigo_movimiento / Foreign Key-> codigo_producto

Estas serían las dos tablas a relacionar, y utilizo el `Laravel collective`

Se supone que debería de quedarme tal que así:

En `MovimientosController`

```
$productos = Producto::lists('nombre','codigo_producto'); /Este a veces me da error por que no se exactamente como ponerlo si en una funcion publica o como.
```

En `create.blade`

```
{!! Form::label('codigo_producto', 'Código del Producto') !!}
{!! Form::text('codigo_producto', $productos, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Código del producto', 'required']) !!}
```

En `edit.blade`

```
{!! Form::label('codigo_producto', 'Código del Producto') !!}
{{ Form::model($productos, array('route' => array('admin.productos.index', $productos->codigo_producto))) }}
```

Pero el caso es que el campo desaparece del formulario directamente ni aparece, lo dejo como estaba y claro funciona, pero no muestra las claves foraneas.

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es tu problema, no veo en qué momento estás usando las llaves foráneas. ¿Qué falla y cuál es el comportamiento deseado?

Comment: el comportamiento deberia de ser el siguiente: En la tabla Movimientos debe de aparecer la Select con los datos de la tabla Productos, es decir es una select dependiente con los datos que haya en otra tabla, y no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo `lists` ya no funciona, tenés que usar `pluck`.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results
Retrieving A List Of Column Values

If you would like to retrieve a Collection containing the values of a single column, you may use the  pluck method. In this example, we'll retrieve a Collection of role titles:

```
$titles = DB::table('roles')->pluck('title');

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo $title;
}
```

You may also specify a custom key column for the returned Collection:

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')->pluck('title', 'name');

foreach ($roles as $name => $title) {
    echo $title;
}
```

Comment: No consigo que salga un select con los datos de otra tabla :S

Comment: @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés Si no te funciona el select, entonces ¿por qué aceptaste esta respuesta?

Comment: @Shaz El select seguramente le funciona, pero al parecer el esta necesitando alguna otra cosa que no estoy entendiendo.